# How install Mailparse php 5.6 centos-webpanel

Tags: php

I'm trying to recompile PHP 5.6.14 with ***mailparse*** on CentOS 6 x68, but I'm getting this error:

```
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-mailparse
```

This is my configure Command :

```
'./configure' '--with-zlib' '--enable-soap' '--enable-exif' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php/php.d' '--enable-phar' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--with-curl' '--with-iconv' '--with-mysql' '--with-mysqli' '--with-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-mcrypt' '--with-gettext' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--enable-posix' '--enable-ftp' '--with-openssl' '--enable-mbstring' '**--enable-mailparse**' '--with-kerberos' '--with-xsl' '--with-bz2' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-zip' '--with-gd' '--with-pcre-regex' '--libdir=/usr/lib' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl'
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it? I'm using centos-webpanel/CWP

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't install the mailparse extension?

https://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse

it's much easier instead of recompile the complete PHP version.